# The problem of declaring a type in the const method and not declaring it in a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I was applying the layout by referring to the official NextJS document.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts

```
// _app.tsx
export type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
  auth?: boolean;
};
```

It worked when the type used 'const' as a component function declaration method, but it didn't apply when it was used as a 'function'.

```
// index.tsx

const LoginPage:NextPageWithLayout = () =>{
  return (
    <>
<h1>Start</h1>
    </>
  );
}

LoginPage.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return (
    <>
      {page}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

no type error

```
function LoginPage():NextPageWithLayout {
  return (
    <>Start</>
  );
}

LoginPage.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return (
    <>
      {page}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

type error

how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure this compiles - "const LoginPage:NextPageWithLayout = ..." ? This is not the correct way to define a function's return type.

Comment: @Anton Podolsky yes, it works. This is an example taken from the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fundamental concept involved: **function declaration** vs **function expression**.

```js
function LoginPage () {
  // this is a "function declaration"
}
```

```js
const LoginPage = () => { 
  // this is a "function expression"
}
```

One of the key differences between them is, with the **function expression**, you assign a function to a variable, then when used with typescript,

```
const LoginPage: NextPageWithLayout = () => { ... }
```

You are actually assigning the `NextPageWithLayout` type to the LoginPage **variable**, so the function is unaffected and you can return a ReactElement from it.

But with

```
function LoginPage(): NextPageWithLayout { ... }
```

You are actually assigning the `NextPageWithLayout` type to the LoginPage **function**, hence the type error as it expects `NextPageWithLayout`, not `ReactElement` in return.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
If so, is there a way to specify that type with a "function declaration"?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: as stated above, when you use the function declaration for LoginPage, and with it returns a ReactElement, you cannot assign the NextPageWithLayout type to it. That's just not correct.

Comment: thank you I don't have to worry any more.